# Export RGB values from node setup by Python

Tags: python

I have a node setup that assigns different colors to an array of objects. The "W" value of the Noise texture is animated so that the rectangles change colors "randomly" during the animation.
I need to output the RGB values for all objects and all frames. I have read online that it is not possible to access the current Node output as it is only available after rendering. It seems weird to me that this would not be possible.
Here is a script that I am currently using - however it outputs RGB = [0,0,0] due to the fact described above.
Is there a way to get the RGB values for each frame? Maybe baking the material or something like this?

```
import bpy
sce = bpy.context.scene

scene_frames = 250

print('***START***')

for f in range(sce.frame_start, scene_frames):
    sce.frame_set(f)
    # get the material
    mat = bpy.data.materials['drone_0']
    # get the nodes
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    # get some specific node:
    # returns None if the node does not exist
    diffuse = nodes.get("Diffuse BSDF")
#    r = int(diffuse.color[0]*255)
#    g = int(diffuse.color[1]*255)
#    b = int(diffuse.color[2]*255)
#    print(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[:])
    r = int(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[0]*255)
    g = int(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[1]*255)
    b = int(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[2]*255)
#    print(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs["Color"])
#    print(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].outputs["BSDF"])
#    print(mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].outputs["BSDF"])
    print("frame:", f,"R:", r, "G:", g, "B:", b)
 
print('***END***')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I would try reimplementing the node graph in Python (since it's a bunch of random stuff you don't have to do it exactly), or if you _must_ replicate what Blender does exactly, rendering each frame and color-picking from the renders to get the colors.

Comment: Thanks, the above is just an example. In reality I need to export RGB values for 50 objects (which are moving) during 8000 frames so color-picking from renders is not really feasible for me. Maybe the Open shade language could help with this? But I have zero experience with it.